How to run local python script on remote respberry pi from windows command prompt
I have my raspberry pi connected in the network on which I have to run the python script. This python script is stored locally. I am writting command as
type <Python Script> | plink <user>@192.168.0.10 -pw <password> 'python - OFF CSM1'

But it gives me and error as
bash: line 1: python3 - OFF CSM1: command not found
What is a way to do this from windows command prompt?

bash on Raspberry Pi is trying to execute a command python3 - OFF CSM1 instead of python3 because of the quotes. However you can't just pipe a python program to python interpreter anyway. Can you explain what the OFF CSM1 is for to clarify what you are trying to do? Are those supposed to be parameters to the script?

@delightfulmemento : Yes OFF and CSM1 are input arguments for python scripts. same command I am running on my Linux system "cat  | sshpass -p '' ssh @192.168.0.10 'python3 - OFF CSM1'", and it is working properly on Raspberry pi

Yes, but plink (see documentation) uses quotes differently than sshpass, so try removing the quotes. I'm not sure if it supports piping that way though, but try it out. (But yeah, my bad, piping to python interpreter apparently works!)

After removing quotes there is different error
"FATAL ERROR: Server refused to start a shell/command"

To give some brief about the application is, I want operate the Relay card connected to my raspberry pi board from my windows command prompt. This is working fine with Linux system, however I am facing trouble with Windows command prompt

for me this works perfectly with PuTTY 0.80 and a debian server (command equivalent to yours but without quotes). try adding -v before the user@host to get additional information about what's happening.

it worked for me now as well after removing quote. I dont know when it was not worked earlier.
Thank you for your help

Consider as python script the following args.py
import sys;  print("First argument is "+sys.argv[1]+" and second argument is "+sys.argv[2])

and execute the following command in Windows (in my case in powershell)
type .\args.py | plink <theuser>@<thehostname> -pw <thepassword> 'python - FOO BAR'

you get the expected result
First argument is FOO and second argument is BAR

And this works with and without quotes, being them either single or double
type .\args.py | plink <theuser>@<thehostname> -pw <thepassword> 'python - FOO BAR'
type .\args.py | plink <theuser>@<thehostname> -pw <thepassword> "python - FOO BAR"
type .\args.py | plink <theuser>@<thehostname> -pw <thepassword> python - FOO BAR

All commands have been verified with powershell 5.1.19041.4170 and 7.4.2 on Windows 10 Enterprise 22H2 connecting on local network to a Raspberry PI running Python 3.9.2 inside Raspberry Pi OS bullseye.
In conclusion, your command is perfectly fine, the issue probably lies in what your answer is not specifying, which is the "<Python Script>".
I am not saying the script is wrong, maybe it only is less "windows-friendly" or "plink-friendly" than needed.
I suggest to start with a simpler script as I did to verify remoting and piping stuff works, then add newlines and richer instructions to deal with your relay board.
